# ValueError: Unable to find resource t64.exe in package pip._vendor.distlib

Tags: python, tox

i am trying to run tox commands but it shows error

```
ValueError: Unable to find resource t64.exe in package pip._vendor.distlib

ERROR: python3.7: could not install deps [-rrequirements.txt]; 
v = InvocationError("'C:\\path\\test_tox\\.tox\\python3.7\\Scripts
\\python.EXE' -m pip install -rrequirements.txt", 2)
```

have tried most of the solution available in internet, but nothing seems to be working. i am not sure what is the root cause of this

`requirements.txt`:

```
dvc
dvc[gdrive]
sklearn
pandas
pytest
tox
```

[image]

Answer (score 84):

Uninstall SetupTools:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
```

Upgrade PIP:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

Reinstall Setuptools:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: Very strange. Here on Win-10 with `Py-3.10.0`, I had to open a an admin pwsh, and run `python -m pip uninstall pip` and then suddenly there was already an instance of the new/latest pip version.There was another version in `c:\users\xxx\appdata\roaming\python\python310\scripts\pip.exe` that took precedence over the *admin* one in: `C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip`.

Comment: @not2qubit this solved it for me, I ran python -m pip uninstall pip and after that I was able to run the normal python  -m pip install --upgrade pip

Answer (score 6):

Below command works for me, thanks to [Colonel Panic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows):

```
python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
python -m ensurepip
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer provided by @techno-appear worked, however I had to do

```bash
py -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

And if that doesn't work, Pip itself advices (through a warning message) to do:

```bash
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```