# I can't upgrade pip

Tags: python

```
PS C:\Users\aslam\OneDrive\Desktop> py -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\aslam\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages (23.2.1)
Collecting pip
  Obtaining dependency information for pip from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/47/6a/453160888fab7c6a432a6e25f8afe6256d0d9f2cbd25971021da6491d899/pip-23.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached pip-23.3.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
Using cached pip-23.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Installing collected packages: pip
  Attempting uninstall: pip
    Found existing installation: pip 23.2.1
    Uninstalling pip-23.2.1:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-23.2.1
  Rolling back uninstall of pip
  Moving to c:\users\aslam\appdata\roaming\python\python312\scripts\
   from C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\~cripts
  Moving to c:\users\aslam\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages\pip-23.2.1.dist-info\
   from C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\~ip-23.2.1.dist-info
  Moving to c:\users\aslam\appdata\roaming\python\python312\site-packages\pip\
   from C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\~ip
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 452, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 72, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 807, in install
    install_wheel(
  File "C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 731, in install_wheel
    _install_wheel(
  File "C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 648, in _install_wheel
    generated_console_scripts = maker.make_multiple(scripts_to_generate)
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 436, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 429, in make
    return super().make(specification, options)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 425, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 325, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 249, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\aslam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 404, in _get_launcher
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Unable to find resource t64.exe in package pip._vendor.distlib

[notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.2.1 -> 23.3.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

while upgrading showing error

to upgrade pip

Comment: Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72150065/valueerror-unable-to-find-resource-t64-exe-in-package-pip-vendor-distlib)